# How to perform incremental broadcast join in spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

When doing broadcast join, it appears that the entire DataFrame is rebroadcasted even if a previous version of it has already been broadcasted.

Consider the following simple example:

```
df3.join(broadcast(df1), on=cond, ,"left_outer")
df3.join(broadcast(df1.union(df2), on=cond, ,"left_outer")
```

I would expect only the df2 portion to be broadcasted, however, it seems as if the entire DataFrame is broadcasted.

The use case for which this is relevant is where df1, df2 etc. represent a hashing map.

The idea is that I have a stream of DataFrames (e.g. generated by foreach on a DStream) on which I need to do an ETL.

The ETL adds another column with some value based on an existing column (hence the broadcast join). The mapping is updated all the time (each time with a small update) based on the previous ETL.

The side of this map can become non-trivial (e.g. hundreds of MB), however, each update is relatively small (e.g. few KB).

Is there any way to perform a broadcast join (or any other means of enrichment) efficiently so that only the newly updated records get broadcasted every time?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know,

```
broadcast(df1)
```

and

```
broadcast(df1.union(df2))
```

broadcasts two different variables. Because the action `df1.union(df2)` actually creates a new DataFrame and is obviously not same as `df1`.

Though the new DataFrame created by the `union` operation contains items of `df1`, `broadcast()` treats them differently. And broadcasts both the DataFrames.

So theoretically, you will have to broadcast both the DataFrames completely to achieve the desired results.
Hope this clears your doubts.

Comment: I understand the mechanics of why this happens. My question is how to get around it. How can I do a broadcast join (or any other means of enrichment) efficiently so that I will need to send updates only and not broadcast the entire thing

Comment: Ok. Instead of joining the same df3 with two DataFrames, how about joining incrementally? Somewhat like this:
```df3 = df3.join(broadcast(df1), on=cond, ,"left_outer"); 
df3.join(broadcast(df2), on=cond, ,"left_outer")
```

Comment: If I do the joining incremenetally it will do two joins (which probably costs more than sending the entire data twice). I originally thought catalyst might optimize this, however, using explain one case see both broadcastHashJoin

Comment: You have to perform two joins in any case right? I didn't understand this part *I originally thought catalyst might optimize this, however, using explain one case see both broadcastHashJoin*

Comment: I need to perform once a join on df1 and once on df1.union(df2). In this example both apply to df3 but that not necessarily the case. So if I do the second join as two joins I would have a total of 3 joins (one for df1, another for df2 in the second join and one for df2). As for catalyst optimizing, I thought that if I do df3.join(broadcast(df1), ...).join(broadcast(df2)...) catalyst would know to do both joins at the same time but if you do explain you see there are still two joins (this actually makes sense because doing two joins is not 100% the same as doing both joins at the same time).

Comment: Ok. My point is, doing `df3.join(broadcast(df1)` and then `df3.join(broadcast(df1.union(df2))` is as same as just doing `df3.join(broadcast(df1.union(df2))`. Isn't it so?

Comment: First they are not the same. join(union) gives the columns once while join(df1).join(df2) would have separate columns to df1 and df2. Second, the example is simplified. In practice the second join could be df4.join(...) The main point is avoid rebroadcasting everything.